# Unable to get output buffers (err=-38) when attempting to screen-record emulator from ADB

Tags: adb, android-emulator, screencast

I am attempting to capture a video of my emulator device screen using the `screenrecord` feature in `ADB`. When I run the command `adb shell screenrecord --verbose /sdcard/demo/capture.mp4` I get the following response from `ADB`;

> Main display is 1440x2560 @60.00fps (orientation=0)
>
> Configuring recorder for 1440x2560 video/avc at 4.00Mbps
>
> Content area is 1440x2560 at offset x=0 y=0
>
> Unable to get output buffers (err=-38)
>
> Encoder failed (err=-38)
>
> Stopping encoder and muxer 218|root@generic_x86_64:/ #

Comment: Which version of Android?

Comment: @MarkYisri, I think 4.2 or 4.4 because I'm having a similar problem!

Comment: It's version 6.0

Answer (score 6):

From ADB documentation :

> "Some devices might not be able to record at their native display
>   resolution. If you encounter problems with screen recording, try using
>   a lower screen resolution."

Documentation link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#screenrecord

Try to use the size option :

> **--size widthxheight**
>
> Sets the video size. The default value is the device's native display resolution (if supported), 1280x720 if
>   not. For best results, use a size supported by your device's Advanced
>   Video Coding (AVC) encoder.